# Array of pointers to array of int

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

After a lot of fight I figured out in a declaration like int A[2][3], A is of a type compatible with **int(*)[3]** . My understanding is A can be used to point to the first three elements and A + 1 to the next three.
Is there any way I can declare an array of pointers to array.

```
   ptr_array    

    +----+                  +----+----+----+                        
    |    |        ---->     |    |    |    |
    |    |                  | 24 | 25 | 26 | 
    +----+                  +----+----+----+
    |    |                  | 44 | 45 | 46 |
    |    |         ---->    |    |    |    |
    +----+                  +----+----+----+
 Array of pointers          two dimensional array of three integers   
   to array of 3
```

How do I declare ptr_array, so that

```
ptr_array[0] = A;
```

and

```
ptr_array[1] = A + 1;
```

Comment: Your understanding is wrong:  `A` is not a pointer at all.  It is an array.  An array is not a pointer.

Comment: Sorry I meant a type compatible with .. Meaning I can say for example int (*s)[3] = A , although A is an array

Comment: Two excellent resources for understanding complex declarations in C:
(1) The clockwise/spiral rule: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html
(2) cdecl: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: One more: declaration as use, as described in ["The Development of the C Language"](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html). There's no way to link to the exact section, but you can read an extract at: ["Complex C type declarations, the easy way"](http://blog.oudamou.co.cc/2009/12/complex-c-type-declarations-easy-way.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multidimensional arrays in C are arrays of arrays. The elements of an n-dimensional array are (n-1) dimensional arrays. `A[0]`, for example, is an `int [3]`.

```
A:    |24|25|26|44|45|46|
A[0]: |24|25|26|
A[1]: |44|45|46|
```

In certain contexts, an array is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array, but the array is not itself a pointer.

From the C standard, § 6.5.2.1-3:

> 3 Successive subscript operators designate an element of a multidimensional array object. If *E* is an n-dimensional array (n≥2) with dimensions i× j×...×k, then *E* (used as other than an lvalue) is converted to a pointer to an (n − 1)-dimensional array with dimensions j × . . . × k. If the unary * operator is applied to this pointer explicitly, or implicitly as a result of subscripting, the result is the pointed-to (n − 1)-dimensional array, which itself is converted into a pointer if used as other than an lvalue. It follows from this that arrays are stored in row-major order (last subscript varies fastest).
>
> 4 EXAMPLE Consider the array object defined by the declaration
>
> ```
> int x[3][5];
> ```
>
> Here x is a 3 × 5 array of ints; more precisely, x is an array of three element objects, each of which is an array of five ints. In the expression `x[i]`, which is equivalent to `(*((x)+(i)))`, x is first converted to a pointer to the initial array of five ints. Then i is adjusted according to the type of x, which conceptually entails multiplying i by the size of the object to which the pointer points, namely an array of five int objects. The results are added and indirection is applied to yield an array of five ints. When used in the expression `x[i][j]`, that array is in turn converted to a pointer to the first of the ints, so `x[i][j]` yields an int.

To create a `ptr_array` as diagrammed:

```
int (*ptr_array[2])[3]
ptr_array[0] = A;
ptr_array[1] = A+1;
// or:
ptr_array[0] = &A[0];
ptr_array[1] = &A[1];
// or even:
ptr_array[0] = (int(*)[3])A[0];
ptr_array[1] = (int(*)[3])A[1];
// though this last shouldn't be used in production code
```

Here's how to work out the declaration. From the diagram, ptr_array is an array of size 2.

```
... ptr_array[2] ...
```

The elements of the array are pointers

```
*ptr_array[2]
```

to arrays of size 3

```
(*ptr_array[2])[3]
```

of ints

```
int (*ptr_array[2])[3]
```

If you're ever not certain how to declare something like this, you can use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/):

```
cdecl> declare ptr_array as array 2 of pointer to array 3 of int
int (*ptr_array[2])[3]
```

You can install a command line version of cdecl (if not already installed) on your development computer. The exact method depends on the platform. Check the documentation and web at large.

Comment: @outis.. Yes int (*ptr_array[2])[3] is exactly what I was looking for! excellent explanation ! learnt something new today.

Answer (score 2):

> In a declaration like `int A[2][3]`, `A` is of a pointer to an array of 3 which means `A` is of type `int(*)[3]`

No.  `A` is an array, not a pointer.  It is of type `int [2][3]`.

> How do I declare ptr_array, so that
>
> ```
> ptr_array[0] = A;
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> ptr_array[1] = A + 1;
> ```

If by `A+1` you mean "the second length-3 array", then you simply need to do this:

```
int (*ptr_array)[3] = A;
```

An array **decays** to become a pointer to its first element in most situations.  I suggest reading the C FAQ on arrays and pointers: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer

Comment: @BlackBear: Answer completed now!

Comment: Sorry I meant a type compatible with .. Meaning I can say for example int (*s)[3] = A , although A is an array ... so like you said ptr_array is still not an array. It is a pointer to an array of 3.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can declare an array to be of anything you like.

Your declaration

```
int A[2][3];
```

defines a two-dimensional array of ints, of size 2x3. `A[0]` is a pointer to *the start of* an array of 3 ints, as is `A[1]`. `A[0][0]` is the first element in the first array. `A[1][2]` is the last element of the last array.

Comment: `&A + sizeof(*int)`?  o_O  Your explanation of what `A` is is incorrect:  in `int A[2][3]` (not `int[2][3] A`), there are no pointers.  An array is not "just a pointer, really."

Comment: I dont think what you said is right. A[0] is a pointer to int. You can verify this with running these statments with gcc with -Wall option                                            int (*ptr)[3] = A[0]; //incompatible pointer type
int *int_ptr = A[0]; //no warning

Comment: oops, sorry guys. I goofed on that one. Edited to fix.

Answer (score -1):

A[2][3] is more an array than a pointer. There are only some cases you can consider array as pointers. A is an array to 6 integers. A is of type integer array.

You can declare **ptr_array[0] as A[0] and ptr_array as A[1].**

Comment: It's not "more an array than a pointer", it **is** an array.  "A is of type integer array" doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: I mean it should be considered as an array rather than treating A as a pointer.